# Get a raw value of excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I am trying to print the post excerpt using the following code:

```
<?php echo $post->post_excerpt;  ?>
```

It works fantastic the only problem is that apparently I get also predefined styles and I cannot get rid of them. How can I get the raw text - is there a different function or maybe there is a php function that returns text only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the PHP [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function should clean out the unwanted HTML elements.

```
<?php
echo strip_tags( $post->post_excerpt );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the WorPress [wp_strip_all_tags()](http://wpseek.com/wp_strip_all_tags/) function you can properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.

```
<?php 
echo wp_strip_all_tags( $post->post_excerpt );
?>
```

**Note:**

1).wp_strip_all_tags fx properly strip all HTML tags including script and style.while [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) strip HTML and PHP tags from a string only.

2).pass second parameter true if you want to remove break tag `<br/>` also.

```
<?php 
   echo wp_strip_all_tags( $post->post_excerpt, true );
?>
```